# How can I mix audio in FFmpeg for voice over music so music quiets only during periods of narration?

Tags: ffmpeg, voiceover

Typically, when there is background music, it gets quieter when a narrator speaks. It should have a slight fade shortly before the narration begins, then a fade back to full volume shortly after any narration finishes. I haven't found any way to do specify times for fade out and back in with ffmpeg (short of highly manual approaches by breaking up the music into separate files at different volume levels before mixing with the voice, but that doesn't scale well to handling a high volume of files).

I know I can adjust the timings with adelay and the relative audio volumes with amix and the weights parameter, but that sets relative volumes for the entire duration of the audio file, not limited to the periods during and immediately around the narration. Is there a way to have the mix only quiet the music track during specified time intervals so I can quiet the music around the voice?

For example:

- 5 minutes of music defining the total audio timespan
- 2 pieces of narration:

  1. One starting at 0:34 with a duration of 45 seconds.
  2. The other starting at 4:00 with a duration of 15 seconds.

Music should play at full volume until 0:32 seconds (fade should start ~2 seconds before the narration), then fade down to 20% volume until 1:20 (0:34 + 45s + 1s before starts coming back), then unfade back to full volume until 3:58, fade back down to 20%, then unfade at 4:16.

**Note**: I'm not asking how to have the music auto quiet when there's narration (because I assume that's not possible, if there is a way to do that, I would be curious to learn that too), just how to specify times to fade to a certain level during a merge, then the time to come back up to full volume. Ideally, I would be able to specify the times to set a rate of fade and rate of resume.